# Is there a way I can create projects in code blocks?

Tags: graphics, linker, project, codeblocks, libraries

I am a novice programmer .I started off by learning all the basics of c programming. After I finished I wanted to now create real apps . but I am completely stuck. I don't where to begin. I am here for guidance on what I should do to create an app in c language. Please I will be very grateful for your guidance. To be specific i need to understand how i can implement the code that I have written. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately the question is far too broad to meet the SO guidelines, please review  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. There are many possible answers to tools and processes you could use in development- so it's not possible to answer unless the question is more specific. If you meant the specific IDE Code:Blocks, it's still too broad a question - you would be better off with a tutorial on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

From the 'file' menu, choose 'new' and then 'project'. 
This command starts the wizard for choosing the type of project you want to create. It can be, for example, a console project, or with a GUI interface or with OpenGL graphics, etc. 
When you have chosen between the different options, CodeBlocks will create a directory (which will be called with the same name as the project).
Warning: the path you choose must not contain spaces (for example it's ok: `C:/cpp/MyFirstProject`)
[image]